# Installing SenticNet package on Anaconda gives UnicodeDecodeError

Tags: python, anaconda

When I try to install SenticNet for sentiment analysis using Conda it cannot find it. Then I tried pip install and I got the error:

```
Collecting senticnet   Using cached senticnet-0.3.3.tar.gz
    Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 20, in <module>
      File "C:\Users\A00220~1\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-ez4td4hb\senticnet\setup.py", line 20, in <module>
        license=open('LICENSE').read(),
      File "C:\Anaconda3\lib\encodings\cp1252.py", line 23, in decode
        return codecs.charmap_decode(input,self.errors,decoding_table)[0]
    UnicodeDecodeError: 'charmap' codec can't decode byte 0x9d in position
181: character maps to <undefined>
```

I have Anaconda 64-bit, python 3.4.3 and pip 7.0.3

Answer (score 0):

This is due to Python not opening the file as UTF-8 when reading.  It appears like Windows does not use Unicode by default so you have to pass in `encoding='utf-8'` to the call to open.  Looking at your error code, you need to change line 20 in `setup.py` to

```
license=open('LICENSE', encoding='utf-8').read()
```

For more information, checkout [Python's Unicode HOWTO](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/unicode.html#reading-and-writing-unicode-data) specifically the reading and writing of data.

Answer (score 0):

Clone the github repository from:

```
https://github.com/yurimalheiros/senticnetapi
```

After unzipping the file, open setup.py and replace line number 20 with:

license=open('LICENSE', encoding='utf-8').read()

after this, open command prompt here(make sure you have environment variable set for python)

run the command -> 'python setup.py install'

This will install senticnet for python, now to get it running in Anaconda, copy the following folder:

C:\Users\HP\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\Lib\site-packages\senticnet-1.3-py3.6.egg\senticnet

to:

C:\Users\HP\Anaconda4\Lib\site-packages\senticnet
(the path will be different based upon your configurations)