# install senticnet in python 3.5

Tags: windows-8, installation, python-3.5

I'm trying to install `senticnet` on `python 3.5` in `windows 8` using `pip` like this :

```
pip install senticnet
```

In the end of the installation I get this error :

```
  Using cached senticnet-1.0.1.tar.gz
    Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
      File "C:\Users\2017\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-bzamjfpz\senticnet\setup.py", line 20, in <module>
        license=open('LICENSE').read(),
      File "f:\python35\lib\encodings\cp1252.py", line 23, in decode
        return codecs.charmap_decode(input,self.errors,decoding_table)[0]
    UnicodeDecodeError: 'charmap' codec can't decode byte 0x9d in position 186 : character maps to <undefined>

    ----------------------------------------
```

I tried the suggested solution in [Installing SenticNet package on Anaconda gives UnicodeDecodeError](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30796090/installing-senticnet-package-on-anaconda-gives-unicodedecodeerror) but I didn't find the `setup.pip` file.
Can anyone help me ?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is the encoding.
Open "setup.py", find "license=open('LICENSE').read()", add "encoding='latin-1'" in the open method. i.e.:
license=open('LICENSE', encoding='latin-1').read()
It works for me.